# Detecting iOS Devices position indoors

Tags: iphone, gps, coordinates, core-location

How can one accurately locate an iOS device indoors?

If the GPS cannot be used correctly indoors, what other way can one track and locate an iOS Device indoors?

Are there any other APIs that are private but allowed by apple?

Is CoreLocation based completely off the GPS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, the CoreLocation API will always return you a location. I'm not sure if you can set it somewhere, but CoreLocation is able to establish your location in multiple ways;

- GSM/CDMA triangulation
- WiFi triangulation
- GPS

So if GPS is unavailable, chances are any of the other 2 will give you a result (though not as precise). If none of the above work, it might give you a cached result or you are simply out of luck.

So, there is no need to call another API; one API will do just fine and make decisions for you based on availability.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good solution for precise indoor positioning. MiRAGe is correct in his explain ation of CoreLocation.